# Error while creating the document set in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013, document-set

I want to create the document set in sharepoint 2013. While creating the documentset I am getting below error
"A duplicate content type "Content type Name" was found."

After going back to the Library. Document set is created.

Need help on this please

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Did you encounter this error when adding document set content type to a library or creating a document set in a library? Could you trace more clues to this error in ULS logs? Take a reference to this article: https://mattjimison.com/2011/06/21/a-duplicate-content-type-found-error/.